# Mirrored text when changing a combobox RTL style

Tags: windows, winapi, combobox, wtl

I'm trying to create a dynamic dialog, which can be made RTL depending on the language. But I have the following issue: whenever I change the RTL style of the combo box, the text comes up reversed. I tried using functions such as `InvalidateRect`, `RedrawWindow`, etc., but couldn't make it work correctly.

Relevant code (WinAPI with WTL):

```
CComboBox combo = hWndCtl;
if(combo.GetCurSel() == 0)
    combo.ModifyStyleEx(WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL, 0);
else
    combo.ModifyStyleEx(0, WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL);
```

A demo project: [here](https://mega.nz/#!ApElkBwT!SQyIm2JjbAdmYS3amsDQCi1Noqm2qCP6UAnVpsiT6bA).

A demonstration of the issue:

[image]

Comment: **This is not an answer; it is a diagnosis. If the answer is "it redraws correctly", then the suggestion here should not be taken as "the answer", but proves an idea that I have about what's going on based on prior experience.**: what happens if you call `InvalidateRect()` in the handler for, say, `WM_USER+5` in your parent window's window procedure, and call `PostMessage(parent window, WM_USER+5, 0, 0)` or similar after changing the extended style? Does it redraw correctly, or does it stay flipped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are responding to `CBN_SELCHANGE` notification. This is notification is sent after combobox sets the text in its editbox.

You should respond to `CBN_SELENDOK` instead. `CBN_SELENDOK` is sent before `CBN_SELCHANGE`, this gives you time to modify the style before combobox sets the text.

```
switch (HIWORD(wParam))
{
case CBN_SELENDOK:// CBN_SELCHANGE:
    if (SendMessage(hComboBox, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0) == 0)
        ModifyStyleEx(hComboBox, WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL, 0);
    else
        ModifyStyleEx(hComboBox, 0, WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL);
    break;
default:break;
}
```

---

---

Edit: Windows 10 has fade in/out effect. If you change the combo selection with keyboard, while the color is fading, the text is still goes backward.

ComboBox has an edit control which might be causing this problem. It's better to use  `WS_EX_RIGHT | WS_EX_RTLREADING` instead of `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL`. This will also work with `CBN_SELCHANGE`.

```
case CBN_SELENDOK: //(or CBN_SELCHANGE)
    if (SendMessage(hComboBox, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0) == 0)
        ModifyStyleEx(hComboBox, WS_EX_RIGHT | WS_EX_RTLREADING, 0);
    else
        ModifyStyleEx(hComboBox, 0, WS_EX_RIGHT | WS_EX_RTLREADING);
    break;
```

Comment: Thank you, that indeed fixed the issue, at least in the common case of selecting an item with the mouse. There are still occurrences of if, e.g. when using the mouse wheel or the keyboard, but I can live with that. Of course, if you have a solution to this as well, let me know.
http://i.imgur.com/Pnz8raX.gif

Comment: I couldn't duplicate the error with mouse wheel, but the key controls cause annoying display errors as you said. I think the solution is using `WS_EX_RIGHT | WS_EX_RTLREADING`